# Как автоматически добавить в Json еще данных с помощью кода не залезая в Json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Мне нужно чтобы код мог сам добавить данные в Json
Я пытался но особо не вышло :(
структура Json:

```
{
  "a": {
    "name":"base",
    "num":"400"
  },
  "b": {
    "name":"home",
    "num":"10"
  }
}
```

код:

```
import json
import dpath.util
with open('base.json',encoding="utf-8") as f:
    templates=json.load(f)
while True:
    b=input()
    if b in templates:
        c=dpath.util.get(dpath.util.search(templates, b), "**/name")
        d=dpath.util.get(dpath.util.search(templates, b), "**/num")
        print(f"Название:{c},ID:{d}")
    else:
        print("Нет в базе , для добавления введите 'y'")
        f=input("")
        if f=="y":
            with open('base.json',"w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
                #запись
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант решения. `json.load()` в данном случае возвращает вложенный словарь, поэтому импортировать `dpath` не требуется. Встроил еще выход из бесконечного цикла. Поскольку много ручного ввода, целесообразно добавить проверки введенных значений.

```
import json

fname = r'c:\test\base.json'
with open(fname, encoding="utf-8") as f:
    templates = json.load(f)

while True:
    b = input("Введите ключ (для выхода введите пустую строку): ")
    if b in templates:
        print(f"Название:{templates[b]['name']},ID:{templates[b]['num']}")
    elif not b:
        break
    else:
        f = input("Нет в базе, для добавления введите 'y': ")
        if f.casefold() == "y":
            data = input(f"Введите 'name' и 'num' для ключа `{b}` через пробел: ").split()
            templates[b] = {'name': data[0], 'num': data[1]}
            with open(fname, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                json.dump(templates, f, indent=2)
```

На входе base.json:

```
{
  "a": {
    "name":"base",
    "num":"400"
  },
  "b": {
    "name":"home",
    "num":"10"
  }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Введите ключ (для выхода введите пустую строку): a
Название:base,ID:400
Введите ключ (для выхода введите пустую строку): b
Название:home,ID:10
Введите ключ (для выхода введите пустую строку): c
Нет в базе, для добавления введите 'y': y
Введите 'name' и 'num' для ключа `c` через пробел: dacha 150
Введите ключ (для выхода введите пустую строку): 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

На выходе base.json:

```
{
  "a": {
    "name": "base",
    "num": "400"
  },
  "b": {
    "name": "home",
    "num": "10"
  },
  "c": {
    "name": "dacha",
    "num": "150"
  }
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо